# Filter in Array of objects for specific object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I know that if I have for example an array like this

```
locations = [
    {
      name: 'location 1',
      id: '1',
      coordinates: {long: '', lat: ''}
    },
    {
      name: 'location 2',
      id: '2',
      coordinates: {long: '', lat''}
    },
];
```

I could filter out by name (or id):

```
locations.filter(function(location){ return location.name === "location 1" })
```

However, I'm trying to get every object that has the 'coordinates' object to be filtered or pushed to a new array, so that only the ones with the 'coordinates' object are left. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: In your filter function: `return location.hasOwnProperty("coordinates")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to do this, Check `coordinates`. You don't require to push into another array as `filter` returns a new array anyway.

```js
  var locations = [
    {
      name: 'location 1',
      id: '1',
      coordinates: {long: '', lat: ''}
    },
    {
      name: 'location 2',
      id: '2',
      coordinates: {long: '', lat:''}
    },
    {
      name: 'location 3',
      id: '3',
    },
];

var res =   locations.filter((location) =>  location.coordinates);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const locations = [
    {
      name: 'location 1',
      id: '1',
      coordinates: {long: 1, lat: 1}
    },
    {
      name: 'location 2',
      id: '2',
      coordinates: {long: 2, lat: 2}
    },
    {
      name: 'location 3',
      id: '3',
    },
];

const filterLocation = (locations) => {
    let filteredLocations = []
    locations.filter((location) => { 
        if(location.hasOwnProperty("coordinates")) {
            filteredLocations.push(location)
        }
    })
    return filteredLocations
}

const newLocations = filterLocation(locations);
console.log('newLocations', newLocations);
```

this will return a new array location without the location 3 in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter based on the cordinates value like below.

```js
let locations = [{name: 'location 1', id: '1', coordinates: {long: '', lat: ''} }, { name: 'location 2', id: '2', coordinates: {long: '', lat:''} } ];
let coordinates = locations.filter(l => !!l.coordinates);
console.log(coordinates);
```